# Save Duplicate Values From String

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have:

```
string turtle = "turtle"
var charArray = turtle.ToCharArray()
```

When I do:

```
var distinct = charArray.Distinct().ToArray()
// distinct = ["t","u","r","l","e"]
```

My question is:

How do I save the characters that got deleted from `charArray` when I called Distinct on it? How do I get the variable distinct to equal `"t"` (the character that was removed)

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245369/how-do-i-get-an-array-of-repeated-characters-from-a-string-using-linq

Comment: remove string distinct from the input string (turtle) and get the delete characters. see this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201595/c-sharp-simplest-way-to-remove-first-occurance-of-a-substring-from-another-str

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GroupBy` to return only the letters `having count > 1`:

```
string turtle = "turtle";
var dups = (from l in turtle
            group 1 by l into g
            where g.Count() > 1
            select g.Key).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var nonUniqueChars = charArray.GroupBy(x => x)
.Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
.Select(x => x.First())
```

This will organize group all the characters that appear, find the ones that appear more than once, and then pull a single instance of each such character.