# Find each non-unique character in a string

Tags: regex

Experiencing a bit of a conundrum here. What I'd like to do is create a regular expression that will in fact return 6 matches for a string like:

*abbccddeeffa*

There are 6 unique characters there, all appearing twice. However, no matter what I try, I can't seem to accomplish this with regular expressions.

```
(.).*\1
```

Will return 1

So, I figured greedieness was the problem there.

```
(.).*?\1
```

Still 1. OK, lookahead instead then?

```
(.).*?(?=\1)
```

Still 1.

Using both https://regexr.com/ and https://regex101.com/ to experiment and test.

The use case is tied to the password strength indicator in my personal written password manager.

I'd like a regular expression that will tell me exactly how many characters in a password such as

W&Nw8uD(Ta*^T6t0n3%!l9.ln1Wo._U

appear more than once. The answer in that case being 5: *W* *w* *T* *n* *l*

Comment: Can you use other things than regex? Or can you sort the string prior to matching?

Comment: Yes, I could just do it in the password manager's language (C#) but that would just be dreadfully slow by comparison. Sorting is an interesting idea though. But that might be complicated as well given the wildly random nature of the strings.

Comment: Not an expert in C#, but I'm sure there is a builtin sort function that will sort strings in alphanumeric order. _Which_ order does not even matter, as long as the same characters are next to each other. Then you can just check adjacent chars and find duplicates in O(n). Or use some sort of map/dictionary and just count all the characters in O(n).

Comment: If it is done in C#, you might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245369/how-do-i-get-an-array-of-repeated-characters-from-a-string-using-linq, I am just not sure if that can be applied to your scenario as is.

Comment: LINQ is a valid option but dreadfully slow by comparison. Thing is, calculating a password's strength happens for each iteration of, for example, my password generation loop. But the suggestion and the reference link are appreciated regardless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will add a code based solution to the top of the answer since you mentioned C# in the comments, as it seems to be the easiest C# approach to get all the repeated chars in the string (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245369/how-do-i-get-an-array-of-repeated-characters-from-a-string-using-linq)):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var s = "abbccddeeffa";
        var repeatedChars = s.GroupBy(x => x).Where(y => y.Count() > 1).Select(z=>z.Key);
        Console.Write(string.Join(", ", repeatedChars));
    }
}
// => a, b, c, d, e, f
```

See [the C# demo](https://ideone.com/Z14iyT).

Here, `.GroupBy(x => x)` groups the chars (a `string` is an array of `char`) and stores the same chars under one single `Key`. We get the number of occurrences of each group using `y.Count()` and `.Where(y => y.Count() > 1)` will only fetch the groups that have more than 1 occurrences. The `.Select(z=>z.Key)` will return the chars of the groups that were returned by the preceding expression.

If you are looking for some regex approach, you may use a lookahead for the part after `(.)`:

```
(.)(?=.*\1)
   ^^^^^^^^
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fWUtne/1).

The pattern matches and captures a char into Group 1 with `(.)` and `(?=.*\1)` will only assert (but not consume, i.e. won't add the matched chars to the match value and won't advance the regex index) that there is the same char after any 0+ chars other than line break chars to the left of the current location.

The `(.).*?(?=\1)` pattern does not return the expected results because the `.*?` part is still *consuming*, the regex engine cannot "re-match" the part that already "belongs" to a valid match (the first match for `abbccddeeffa` is `abbccddeeff` and then only `a` remains that cannot be matched with this pattern).

Whether you use `.*?` or `.*` in the looahead is less important if you do not know what kind of input is expected: `.*?` will be more efficient if the repeated char is close to the captured char, `.*` will be better if the repeated chars appear closer to the end of the string.

Comment: Note that this will still return two matches for a character that appears three times.

Comment: @tobias_k True, actually, the task to count chars in the string is not a regex task in general. However, it is clear that whenever there is a match, the amount of the chars is equal to number of matches + 1.

Comment: Good point although for my purposes it does not matter too much, since I just want to count the number of non-unique characters in a string. And not their exact count.

Comment: Just as a follow up: you might want to have a look at [How do I get an array of repeated characters from a string using LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245369/how-do-i-get-an-array-of-repeated-characters-from-a-string-using-linq). To get only unique ones, you would need to use `Where(y => y.Count() == 1)`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew -- Thanks for the regex. Such a very subtle and minor change that was required but it completely escaped me. The beauty of it is that it still remains a very small, simple regular expression, making it very fast. Thanks!

Comment: @zdQTJEnZ Actually, LINQ is also very concise and powerful. I will add more details.

Comment: I should also note that this is on Linux and I am unsure as to how fast or complete Mono's implementation of LINQ is and .NET Core might not even carry it, since it's intended to be the base essentials.

Comment: Come on, I provided a demo on a Linux server using Mono, [this site](https://ideone.com/Z14iyT) uses [Mono 4.6.2](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/4.6.2/).

Comment: @zdQTJEnZ: note that the regex approach is wrong if characters are repeated more than one time.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void FindNonUnique( string searchTerm )
{
    var s = abbccddeeffa;
    var uniqueString = "";
    var uniqueMap = new Dictionary<char,int>();

    foreach( var letter in s )
    {
        if ( uniqueMap.ContainsKey( letter ) == false )
            uniqueMap.Add( letter , 1 );
        else
        {
            if ( uniqueMap[letter] == 1 )
            {
                uniqueString += letter;
                uniqueMap[letter]++;
            }
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine( uniqueString );
}
```